# How to generate a list of all possible 5 alphanumeric in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to generate all possible 5 digit number in python but I was wondering how to generate all possible 5 alphanumeric like 1df52. I can't think of anyway of generating all possible 5 alphanumeric, can anyone point me what can be done here?

Comment: Did you try: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations ?

Comment: Actually someone just pointed that point in answer, am just checking it out.

Answer (score 5):

Use the builtin [`itertools.product()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

In addition, you can use the constants from the `string` module to find out what digits and letters there are. :)

```py
import itertools
import string

keyspace = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase

# (or `itertools.product(keyspace, repeat=5)`)
for combination in itertools.product(*[keyspace] * 5):  
    print(''.join(combination))
```

outputs

```
00000
00001
00002
00003
[...]
032ne
032nf
032ng
[...]
11xbe
11xbf
11xbg
11xbh
11xbi
[...]
```

The slightly arcane `itertools.product(*[keyspace] * 5)` construction means the same as `itertools.product(keyspace, keyspace, keyspace, keyspace, keyspace)`. (The idea is that we repeat the single-item array `[keyspace]` 5 times to get `[keyspace, keyspace, keyspace, keyspace, keyspace]`, then unpack it into separate arguments using the `*` splat operator.

*EDIT:*

To also print how many combinations there are, you can use `enumerate()`:

```py
for num, combination in enumerate(itertools.product('abc', 'def', 'gh'), 1):  
    print(num, ''.join(combination))
```

outputs

```
1 adg
2 adh
3 aeg
4 aeh
5 afg
6 afh
7 bdg
8 bdh
9 beg
10 beh
11 bfg
12 bfh
13 cdg
14 cdh
15 ceg
16 ceh
17 cfg
18 cfh
```

Comment: can we fix a particular space also say I want last one to be a number always or last one to be a char always, can that be fixed?

Comment: @Rootrj Sure, just pass in different things to `product`. For example `product(string.digits, string.ascii_lowercase, 'xy', '6')` would return combinations that always start with a digit, then have a letter, then either x or y, and always a 6.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the quick help @AKX let me play with this new module I just learnt about.

Comment: a small simplification; `product(keyspace, repeat=5)`. as documented in https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yup (it's noted as a comment), but it doesn't help with the OP's secondary request here in the comments. :)

Comment: oops, sorry. did not read the comments as thoroughly as i should have! (actually i still don't find it in the comments here...)

Comment: Hi all, I am playing with this module and learning to use it, I customized it a bit, it generated a list in output, is there any way to know how many such alphanumeric I just generated?

Comment: @Rootrj the number is the product of the lengths of the items you combine... (in the example above: `len('abc') * len('def') * len('gh') = 18`).

Comment: @Rootrj Added an example on `enumerate()`.

Comment: @AKX no not that way, I know about enumerate function but that adds the count in the beginning. I was looking for something in which I would supply my generate file and it would tell how many combination it contains. I believe I would require something which can tell how many lines are there in the file as lines = combinations in this case, that would work.

Comment: @Rootrj Maybe you're just looking at the `wc -l` Unix command.

Comment: yeah wc-l should work, thanks.